# Difference between feature selection, feature extraction, feature weights 

Tags: parallel-processing, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am slightly confused as to what "feature selection / extractor / weights" mean and the difference between them. As I read the literature sometimes I feel lost as I find the term used quite loosely, my primary concerns are --

1. When people talk of Feature Frequency, Feature Presence - is it feature selection?
2. When people talk of algorithms such as Information Gain, Maximum Entropy - is it still feature selection.
3. If I train the classifier - with a feature set that asks the classifier to note the position of a word within a document as an example - would one still call this feature selection?

Thanks
Rahul Dighe

Answer (score 18):

Rahul-

All of these are good answers.  The one thing I would mention is that the fundamental difference between selection and extraction has to do with how you are treating the data.

Feature *Extraction* methods are transformative -- that is you are applying a transformation to your data to project it into a new feature space with lower dimension. PCA, and SVD are examples of this.

Feature *Selection* methods choose features from the original set based on some criteria, Information Gain, Correlation and Mutual Information are just criteria that are used to filter out unimportant or redundant features.  Embedded or wrapper methods, as they are called, can use specialized classifiers to achieve feature selection and classify the dataset at the same time.

A really nice overview of the problem space is given [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.98.1478%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&rct=j&q=dimensionality%20reduction%20UCD-CSI-2007-7&ei=NKULTfWVEIGs8Aayp_2JDg&usg=AFQjCNHi6vUysDS2ToRHu6QQDi3XfLJMsA).

Good Luck!

Comment: really great explanation. Link is dead though ... :)

Answer (score 8):

Feature extraction: reduce dimensionality by (linear or non-
linear) projection of D-dimensional vector onto d-dimensional
vector (d < D).
Example: principal component analysis

Feature selection: reduce dimensionality by selecting subset
of original variables.
Example: forward or backward feature selection

Answer (score 6):

Feature Selection is the process of choosing "interesting" features from your set for further processing.

Feature Frequency is just that, the frequency that a feature appears.

Information Gain, Maximum Entropy, etc. are weighting methods, which use Feature Frequency, which in turn, allow you to perform Feature Selection.

Think of it like this:

You parse a corpus, and create a term / document matrix.  This matrix starts out as a count of the terms, and what document in which they appear (simple frequency).

To make that matrix more meaningful, you weight the terms based on some function including the frequency (like term frequency-inverse document frequency, Information gain, maximum entropy).  Now that matrix contains the weights, or importance of each term in relation to the other terms in the matrix.

Once you have that, you can use feature selection to keep only the most important terms (if you are doing stuff like classification or categorization) and perform further analysis.

Comment: so what is feature extraction ?

Comment: Feature extraction is the process of reducing the dimensionality of your data (usually through SVD, PCA, etc).

See this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_extraction